# How can I get a hash of the contents of a Rails fixture instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, fixtures

This is using Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.2.0.

What I'd like to do is use the data contained in a fixture object to verify that duplicates are caught before insertion into the same database:

```
  test "identical entries should be impossible to create" do
    dup_entry = Entry.new(entries(:test_entry))
    assert_not dup_entry.save
  end
```

(where `Entry` is a well-defined model with a controller method `.new`, and `test_entry` is a fixture containing some valid `Entry` instance.)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because `entries(:test_entry)` is going to be an `Entry`, not a hash accepted by `Entry.new`.

I know that I can access fixture properties with an expression of the form `fixture_objname.property` in the associated tests, since whatever is specified in the YAML will automatically be inserted into the database and loaded. The problem with this is that I have to manually retype a bunch of property names for the object I just specified in the YAML, which seems silly.

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html) also says I can get the actual model instances by adding `self.use_instantiated_fixtures = true` to the test class. However, there don't seem to be any `instance_methods` that will dump out the fixture's model instance (`test_entry`) in a hash format to feed back into the `.new` method.

Is there an idiomatic way to get what I want, or a different, easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
entries(:test_entry).attributes
entries(:test_entry).attributes.class # => Hash
```

You can also remove properties if needed:

```
entries(:admin).attributes.except("id")
```

Hope this helps.